# How to use stl with inheritance?

Tags: c++, stl

How can one call a function with different arguments while the parameter is a list of basic struct and while calling the function the argument is the list of the inherited struct.

It is even possible? I got error

```
no known conversion from list<Stats> to list<MyStats>
```

If anyone knows how to properly name this question or even reformulate it, please do so.

```
struct Stats{
    int number;
};
struct MyStats:Stats{
    char letter;
};
using namespace std;

std::list<Stats> extractFirstBatch(std::list<Stats> stats){
    int counter=0;
    std::list<Stats> batch;
    for(const auto&s: stats){
        counter++;
        batch.push_back(s);
        if(counter>10)
            break;
    }
    return batch;
}
int main()
{
    std::list<MyStats> stats;
    MyStats s;
    s.number=1;
    stats.push_back(s);
    //error no matching function for call to 'extractFirstBatch'
    //no know conversion from list<Stats> to list<MyStats>
    QList<Stats> newStats=extractFirstBatch(stats);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's assume (for sake of discussion, since - as you say - you can't) that the type of conversion you want was possible.   You have a `std::list<Stats>` that is somehow convertible to a `std::list<MyStats>`.     If you access elements of the `std::list<MyStats>`, what values would you expect the `letter` member of those elements to have?   Is your expectation (which may be specific to your particular understanding of the `MyStats` and `Stats` types) going to be relevant to all other types that may be stored in a `std::list`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to use stl with inheritance?

The same way as you use variables with inheritance. You use indirection.

A variable of type `Stats` is always of type `Stats` and not of some derived type. Similarly, the elements of the container `std::list<Stats>` are always of type `Stats` and not of some derived type.

To have runtime polymorphism, we can use indirection. If we have a reference or a pointer to `Stats` it could be a standalone instance of `Stats` or we could be referring to a base sub object of a derived type. So, let use store pointers in the container: `std::list<std::shared_ptr>`. You can alternatively use non-owning pointers if you want to keep the ownership elsewhere and know that there won't be issues with lifetime. Or, if you make `Stats::~Stats` virtual, then you could use unique pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library:

```
std::list<MyStats> result;
std::copy_n(stats.begin(), 10, std::back_inserter(result));
```

`std::back_inserter` returns an iterator that appends to the container. `std::copy_n` copies the specified number of elements.